# Why geolocation is not supporting in my any browser?

Tags: javascript, node.js, html, mean-stack

Why geolocation is not supporting in my any browser ?
I am new in the world of javascript.

Here is my Code which I am running at node js server.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
</head>
<body>
    <button onclick="getLocation()">Get coords</button>
    <h1 id="coords"></h1>
    <script>
        var x=document.getElementById('coords');
        function getLocation(){
            if (navigator.Geolocation) {
               navigator.Geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);
            }
        else{
            x.innerHTML="Geolocation is not supported";
        }
        function showPosition(position){
            console.log(position.coords.latitude);
        }
    }
     </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

[image: This is Output]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pay attention to the capitalization: Change `navigator.Geolocation)` to `navigator.geolocation`.

Documentation of the geolocation API on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation

Answer (score 2):

JavaScript is case sensitive in terms of variable names, APIs etc. Use geolocation without a capital G.

Example from the [MDN article on geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation):

```
if ("geolocation" in navigator) {
  /* geolocation is available */
} else {
  /* geolocation IS NOT available */
}
```